# Choosing the Length of Time Steps in Recurrent Neural Network

Tags: recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I have a time-series regression problem with a single predictor and a real-valued output, and I would like to use LSTM recurrent neural network to model the data. How should I choose the number of time steps in my model? Is there any upper limit for the length of LSTM layer?

Answer (score 0):

LSTMs can be challenging to use when you have very long input sequences and only one or a handful of outputs. A reasonable limit of 250-500 time steps is often used in practice with large LSTM models.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I choose the number of time steps in my model?

It entirely depends on the task at hand, in short the **time series frequency determines this** if the data you have is at the following interval minutes then 60 ,  hours then 24 ,month then 12 and so on.

Simply stating *At what level you need your predictions*

> Is there any upper limit for the length of LSTM layer?

It depends on the quantum of data .
A reasonable limit of 250-500 time steps in good to go. Long input sequences may result in vanishing gradients, and in turn, an unlearnable model